# Cannot remove last row using IF

Tags: python, pandas

I just picked up coding and part of my assignment requires me to find the profitability of stock buy and sell signals. 
So far I have done the overall, however I am unable to remove the last buy, giving me buy-sell-buy, instead of jus buy-sell

```
nss = len(Stock_signals)
for i in range(nss):
   if Stock_signals.Signal[i] == 'Buy':
  break
   else:
  Stock_signals.loc[Stock_signals.index[i] ,'Signal'] = Stock_signals.Signal[i][0]

bi = i
for i in range(bi,nss):
   if Stock_signals.Signal[i] == 'Buy':
      for j in range(i+1,nss):
     if Stock_signals.Signal[j] == 'Buy':
        Stock_signals.loc[Stock_signals.index[j] ,'Signal'] = 'B'
     else:
        break

for i in range(nss):
   if Stock_signals.Signal[i] == 'Sell':
  for j in range(i+1,nss):
     if Stock_signals.Signal[j] == 'Sell':
        Stock_signals.loc[Stock_signals.index[j] ,'Signal'] = 'S'
     else:
        break



if Stock_signals.Signal[-1] == ('B'):
  Stock_signals.loc[Stock_signals.index[-1] ,'Signal'] = Stock_signals.Signal[-1][0]`


Date         Price     Signal                        
2011-02-03  36.060001    Buy

2011-10-31  25.850000   Sell

2011-11-10  22.700001    Buy
```

Comment: This is [tag:pandas], right?

Comment: import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

does this count as pandas?

Comment: Yes, and some others. I'd [edit] to add the modules used as tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you expect this chunk of code:

```
if Stock_signals.Signal[-1] == ('B'):
  Stock_signals.loc[Stock_signals.index[-1] ,'Signal'] = Stock_signals.Signal[-1][0]`
```

to remove this line from the dataframe:

```
2011-11-10  22.700001    Buy
```

but you're checking if `signal == 'B'` rather than `signal == 'Buy'`

try:

```
if Stock_signals.Signal[-1] == ('Buy'):
  Stock_signals = Stock_signals[:-1]
```